# how to pass a method as parameter of other method but making the last method have a generic as parameter on its signature?

Tags: java

I am very novice in generics and now I just found out this.

I have a method

```
//interface
myMethod(MyOtherService service)

//implementation
@Override
public myMethod(MyOtherService service){
   service.doSomething();
}
```

I have to clarify that MyFunction does not extend of other Class

I want to do this

```
//interface
myMethod(GenericFunction function)

//Implementation
@Override
myMethod(GenericFunction function){
//try to cast it to MyOtherService or ServiceABC, etc
if(function instanceof(MyOtherService.class)){
//convert and call to doSomething();
}

}
```

I did that actually and compiler doesn't complain, the problem is I cannot call it with

I would like to use a functional interface (if any) but the problem I have is that doSomething() actually receives multiple parameters.

```
myMethod(myService)
```

since it is expecting a Function instance.

What Im doing wrong? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

By my opinion you just use Object as parameter,See below code,

```
public class system_property implements A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new system_property().myMethod(new MyOtherService());
    }

    @Override
    public void myMethod(Object service) {
        if (service instanceof MyOtherService) {
            System.out.println("YES");
        }
    }

}

interface A {

    void myMethod(Object service);
}

class MyOtherService {

}
```